# RSA encrypting a large file

Tags: c#, base64, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

The thing is I have encrypted a file using rsa using this code that I came up with:

```
        for (int a = 0; a <= iterations; a++)
        {
            byte[] plain;
            int rsaLen = rsa.KeySize / 8 - 11;
            int bytesLen = plain.Length;
            int block = bytesLen - rsaLen * a;

            //The last block in the text may not be a full block
            if (block > rsaLen )
                plain = new byte[maxRsaLength];
            else
                plainblock = new byte[block];

            Buffer.BlockCopy(plaintext, rsaLen * a, plain, 0, plain.Length);

            //purfoming the encryption
            ciphertext.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.Encrypt(plain, false)));
        }
```

the thing is when I try to decrypt I have to convert the ciphertext which i had put to base 64 into a base 64 blocks but then I am getting a bad length exceptioon from the decrypt method of the RSAServiceProvider. I have been following the example written on this site:
http://digitalsquid.co.uk/2009/01/rsa-in-cs/ to no avail. I dont get any encrption errors just decryption. I cant even be sure if I have done the encrytion right. Bellow is my decryption loop:

```
   public string Decrypt(string ciphertext, string key = null)
    {
        //checking for ciphertext. Exception raise if null
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ciphertext)) throw new ArgumentNullException(ciphertext, "There is no ciphertext to decrypt.");

        //String holding the decrypted value
        string plaintext = String.Empty;

        //chanck is the user has provided a key. If not the use the one automatically generated
        string keyToUse = String.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? privatekey : key;

        //set the key
        rsa.FromXmlString(keyToUse);

        //Determine the blocksizes for the iterations
        int blockSize = ((rsa.KeySize / 8) % 3 != 0) ? (((rsa.KeySize / 8) / 3) * 4) + 4 : ((rsa.KeySize / 8) / 3) * 4;

        int iterations = ciphertext.Length / blockSize;
        byte[] allPlaintextAsBytes = new byte[0];


        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                //to decrypt this we have to take the cipher text from a base 64 string an array.
                byte[] cipherTextAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertext.Substring(blockSize * i, blockSize));

                byte[] partialPlaintextAsBytes = rsa.Decrypt(cipherTextAsBytes, false);
            }
        }....(Catch Exceptions down here)
```

I KNOW THAT THIS IS NOT BEST TO SPLIT A FILE TO RSA IT. Yes normally you encrypt the key to a stream cipher like AES with RSA and encrypt the file with AES. This is a project i am doing so I hve to do it this way.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Make sure whoever assigned the project is pointing out that this is stupid to other students who might not know that. It's not just a security convention to do the nested symmetric encryption: it's actively insecure to do direct encryption with RSA. I wouldn't want a generation of students walking away from this project thinking that the practice is in any way okay.

Comment: @MyseriousDan I would disagree a little. Certainly, it's stupid to do it this way. However, "direct" RSA encryption is secure.

Comment: is it a little silly yes. Encrypting with a 512 key or 128 is silly but it helps people starting to understand how these numbers work. The reason  he has asked me to do this is so I get to make this work. Just by doing this project I have learnt so far that block ciphers can not encrypt  blocks bigger than the modulus. I didnt know this before I got the project. I can safely say I am no expert but those that are should not just beat down this question and not even answer it just because  its and unusual way of doing things. The question is about the code I have written not working not concepts

Comment: Oh, I'm not deliberately not answering the question on principle. I don't know the details of the C# crypto API so can't be of much help there. @DuncanJones I'm not sure what you mean by direct RSA encryption, but doing the obvious thing (i.e., raising your cleartext to a modular power) certainly is not secure. The very first iPhone unlock was made possible by Apple engineers (or whoever they contracted for the baseband) not knowing about secure padding schemes and the Bleichenbacher attack on exactly that sort of thing.

Comment: @MyseriousDan I wasn't sure what "direct" meant either - you mentioned it in your first comment. Anyway, if we assume "normal" RSA encryption involves padding the plaintext with a standard scheme such as OAEP, then it is secure.

Answer (score 0):

Real-world RSA implementations do padding which affects the maximum length of the plaintext that can be encrypted.

In particular, PKCS#1 padding (the most common kind) only supports plaintexts that are k - 11 bytes long, where k is the key length. OAEP padding only accepts plaintext's that are up to k - 2 * hash length - 2 long (OAEP lets you change the hash algo you're using).